# (Swift) Function to parse string (from-to)

Tags: string, swift, parsing

**Is any other ways to parse string "from-to"?** 
I mean when there is a value we need and we know about string before and after it.
I`ve just created such function as

```
func parser(textToParse:String, strFrom:String, strTo:String) -> String {
        return textToParse.componentsSeparatedByString(strFrom)[1].componentsSeparatedByString(strTo)[0]
    }
```

And it`s using like

```
var s=parser("abc", strFrom: "a", strTo: "c")
//s will be "b"
```

Comment: So you want to a substring of a string?

Comment: Yea, I want to have possibility to extract a value I need from string knowing strings before and after this value. It`s very useful to get any hashes from html-answers when you making a autorization on any website, for example

Comment: You could use `substringWithRange(<#aRange: Range<String.Index>#>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using `substringWithRange`:

```
func substringBetween(start: String, and end: String) -> String? {
    if let startIndex = rangeOfString(start, options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)?.endIndex,
           endIndex = rangeOfString(end, options: .LiteralSearch, range: startIndex..<self.endIndex, locale: nil)?.startIndex {
        return substringWithRange(startIndex..<endIndex)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```