# Swift Read HTML Tag

Tags: html, swift

I'm working with Swift 2.0, and I'm using `Alamofire` for my REST library. If the call fails, I will need to be able to read the `<title>` tag from the `NSData`. How can I go about reading an `HTML` tag from the `NSData`, or `NSString` which I can convert it to. I really don't want to use regex.

Comment: You can use `NSScanner`.

Comment: use https://github.com/topfunky/hpple for parsing elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try variants from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679148/swift-function-to-parse-string-from-to) question

Just convert your response from NSData to string (or make Alamofire settings such that it will return you string) and use it!